# Today extension - Unable to load

Tags: swift, today-extension

I'm trying to load data into a table in extension today - The data is displayed at 1 start, then the message "Unable to load".

The console does not display any data - What may be the problem?

Here is my code in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
        loader.startAnimating()
        loader.hidesWhenStopped = true

        statusLabel.isHidden = true
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
        tableView.isHidden = true
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "LatestCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "latestCell")

        if(checkDownloadable())
        {
            //Download OFFLINE
            let realm = try! Realm()
            let postsRealm = realm.objects(PostRealm.self)
            var newPosts = [Post]()
            var items: Int {
                if(postsRealm.count > 5)
                {
                    return 5
                }else{
                    return postsRealm.count
                }
            }
            for i in 0..<items {
                let postRealm = postsRealm[i]
                let postStandard = Post.init(id: postRealm.id, title: postRealm.title, date: postRealm.date, url: postRealm.url, content: postRealm.content, image: postRealm.image, authorName: postRealm.authorName, authorImage: postRealm.authorImage)
                newPosts.append(postStandard)
            }
            self.posts = newPosts

            self.loader.stopAnimating()

            if(newPosts.count == 0)
            {
                self.statusLabel.isHidden = false
                self.statusLabel.text = "Brak postów"
                self.tableView.isHidden = true
            }else{
                self.statusLabel.isHidden = true
                self.tableView.isHidden = false
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }else{
            //DOWNLOAD ONLINE
            API.postsWidget(){ post in
                self.posts = post ?? [Post]()
                self.loader.stopAnimating()

                if(post?.count == 0)
                {
                    self.statusLabel.isHidden = false
                    self.statusLabel.text = "Brak postów"
                    self.tableView.isHidden = true
                }else{
                    self.statusLabel.isHidden = true
                    self.tableView.isHidden = false
                }

                for p in self.posts {
                    self.addNewPost(post: p)
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone know what this is about? 
..............................
...........................